# WFFM Roles not working

Tags: wffm, role-management

The following role was assigned to a user, But still not able to view WFFM module in Sitecore

Sitecore\Developer

Sitecore\Designer

Sitecore\Sitecore Client Developing

Sitecore\Sitecore Market Form Author

Sitecore\Sitecore Client Securing

Sitecore\Sitecore Client Forms author

Note: All these role was created with a custom role(SiteContentAuthor) and we also provided the field level restriction to other content items for the SiteContentAuthor role.

Comment: What do you mean with "still not able to view WFFM module in Sitecore" @PVM?

Comment: /sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers folder is not visible. Only the sites inside the  /sitecore/content were visible

Comment: You need to set access to that folder through Security Editor for your role SiteContentAuthor. It won't inherit permissions from other roles...

Comment: Did you try to switch to `View` tab in Content Editor ribbon and check `Entire Tree` checkbox?

Comment: Thanks Marek. I enabled the "Entire Tree" + also looks like need to enable the "Hidden Item" Check box.